# SQL Lite "Unknown Database" Result

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, syntax, varchar

I am trying to reconstitute an old dataset coded with SQL.

When I input the code into SQLlite to execute, it gives:

Execution finished with errors.
Result: unknown database `hookworm`
At line 1:
CREATE TABLE `hookworm`.`screening`
(

Here is one of the (de-identified) tables

```
CREATE TABLE `hookworm`.`screening`
(
   `id` varchar(5) not null,
   `number_pg2` varchar(4) null,
   `1a_pregnant_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1b_breastfeeding_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1c_weightloss_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1d_rinfections_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1e_immunodeficiency__pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1f_corticosteroid_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1g_hypertension_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1h_severeasthma_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1i_chroniccough_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1j_diabetes_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1k_rabdominalpain_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1l_chronicdiabetes_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1m_backjointpain_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1n_neurohllk_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1o_rheadaches_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1p_bcpsych_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1q_anemia_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1r_phookworm_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1s_recentvac_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1t_transfusion_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `1u_alcoholdrugs_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `2_medical_history_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `2a_condition_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `2a_onset_pg2` varchar(12) null,
   `2a_stop_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `2a_ongoing_pg2` varchar(5) null,
   `2b_onset_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `2b_stop_pg2` varchar(9) null,
   `2b_ongoing_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `2c_onset_pg2` varchar(5) null,
   `2c_stop_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `2c_ongoing_pg2` varchar(9) null,
   `2d_onset_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `2d_stop_pg2` varchar(5) null,
   `2d_ongoing_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `2e_onset_pg2` varchar(9) null,
   `2e_stop_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `2_ongoing_pg2` varchar(5) null,
   `3_surgical_history_pg2` varchar(5) null,
   `3a_description_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `3a_date_pg2` varchar(9) null,
   `3b_description_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `3b_date_pg2` varchar(12) null,
   `3c_description_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `3c_date_pg2` varchar(12) null,
   `3d_description_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `3d_date_pg2` varchar(12) null,
   `4_known_allergies_pg2` varchar(255) null,
   `4a_anaphylacti__pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `4b_other_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `4b_description_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `4c_other_pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `4c_description__pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `4d_other__pg2` enum('yes ','no') null,
   `4d_description_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `5_recent_vacination__pg2` varchar(5) null,
   `5a_vaccine_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `5a_date_pg2` varchar(9) null,
   `5b_vaccine_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `5b_date_pg2` varchar(12) null,
   `5c_vaccine_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `5c_date_pg2` varchar(12) null,
   `5d_vaccine_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `5d_date_pg2` varchar(12) null,
   `5e_vaccine_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `5e_date_pg2` varchar(12) null,
   `6_currentmedications_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `6a_medname_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `6a_reason_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `6a_dailydose_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `6a_route_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `6a_onsetdate_pg2` varchar(12) null,
   `6a_stopdate_pg2` varchar(12) null,
   `6a_ongoing_pg2` varchar(5) null,
   `6b_medname_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `6b_reason_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `6b_dailydose_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `6b_route_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `6b_onsetdate_pg2` varchar(12) null,
   `6b_stopdate_pg2` varchar(12) null,
   `6b_ongoing_pg2` varchar(5) null,
   `6c_medname_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `6c_reason_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `6c_dailydose_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `6c_route_pg2` varchar(45) null,
   `6c_onsetdate_pg2` varchar(12) null,
   `6c_stopdate_pg2` varchar(12) null,
   `6c_ongoing_pg2` varchar(5) null,
   `7_reproductivestatus_pg2` enum('male','fsterile','femaleabst','fpostmeno','fchildbearing','') null,
   `8_sugicallysterile_pg2` enum('hysterectomy','tubal ligation','other') null,
   `9_birthcontrol_pg2` enum('barrier','implcontra','transdcontra','iud','injoralcontr','other') null,
   `10_Smenstration_pg2` varchar(12) null,
   `initials_pg2` varchar(5) null,
   `datecomp_pg2` varchar(12) null,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `hookworm`.`screening` (`id`,`number_pg2`,`1a_pregnant_pg2`,`1b_breastfeeding_pg2`,`1c_weightloss_pg2`,`1d_rinfections_pg2`,`1e_immunodeficiency__pg2`,`1f_corticosteroid_pg2`,`1g_hypertension_pg2`,`1h_severeasthma_pg2`,`1i_chroniccough_pg2`,`1j_diabetes_pg2`,`1k_rabdominalpain_pg2`,`1l_chronicdiabetes_pg2`,`1m_backjointpain_pg2`,`1n_neurohllk_pg2`,`1o_rheadaches_pg2`,`1p_bcpsych_pg2`,`1q_anemia_pg2`,`1r_phookworm_pg2`,`1s_recentvac_pg2`,`1t_transfusion_pg2`,`1u_alcoholdrugs_pg2`,`2_medical_history_pg2`,`2a_condition_pg2`,`2a_onset_pg2`,`2a_stop_pg2`,`2a_ongoing_pg2`,`2b_onset_pg2`,`2b_stop_pg2`,`2b_ongoing_pg2`,`2c_onset_pg2`,`2c_stop_pg2`,`2c_ongoing_pg2`,`2d_onset_pg2`,`2d_stop_pg2`,`2d_ongoing_pg2`,`2e_onset_pg2`,`2e_stop_pg2`,`2_ongoing_pg2`,`3_surgical_history_pg2`,`3a_description_pg2`,`3a_date_pg2`,`3b_description_pg2`,`3b_date_pg2`,`3c_description_pg2`,`3c_date_pg2`,`3d_description_pg2`,`3d_date_pg2`,`4_known_allergies_pg2`,`4a_anaphylacti__pg2`,`4b_other_pg2`,`4b_description_pg2`,`4c_other_pg2`,`4c_description__pg2`,`4d_other__pg2`,`4d_description_pg2`,`5_recent_vacination__pg2`,`5a_vaccine_pg2`,`5a_date_pg2`,`5b_vaccine_pg2`,`5b_date_pg2`,`5c_vaccine_pg2`,`5c_date_pg2`,`5d_vaccine_pg2`,`5d_date_pg2`,`5e_vaccine_pg2`,`5e_date_pg2`,`6_currentmedications_pg2`,`6a_medname_pg2`,`6a_reason_pg2`,`6a_dailydose_pg2`,`6a_route_pg2`,`6a_onsetdate_pg2`,`6a_stopdate_pg2`,`6a_ongoing_pg2`,`6b_medname_pg2`,`6b_reason_pg2`,`6b_dailydose_pg2`,`6b_route_pg2`,`6b_onsetdate_pg2`,`6b_stopdate_pg2`,`6b_ongoing_pg2`,`6c_medname_pg2`,`6c_reason_pg2`,`6c_dailydose_pg2`,`6c_route_pg2`,`6c_onsetdate_pg2`,`6c_stopdate_pg2`,`6c_ongoing_pg2`,`7_reproductivestatus_pg2`,`8_sugicallysterile_pg2`,`9_birthcontrol_pg2`,`10_Smenstration_pg2`,`initials_pg2`,`datecomp_pg2`) VALUES ('06999','0000','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','text','00ooo0000','text','yes ','text','00ooo0000','text','yes ','text','00ooo0000','text','yes ','text','00ooo0000','text','yes ','','text','00ooo0000','text','00ooo0000','text','00ooo0000','text','00ooo0000',null,'yes ','yes ','text','yes ','text','yes ','text','yes ','text','00ooo0000','text','00ooo0000','text','00ooo0000','text','00ooo0000','text','00ooo0000','text','text','text','text','text','00ooo0000','00ooo0000','yes ','text','text','text','text','00ooo0000','00ooo0000','yes ','text','text','text','text','00ooo0000','00ooo0000','yes ','male','hysterectomy','barrier','00ooo0000','aaa','00ooo0000');
INSERT INTO `hookworm`.`screening` (`id`,`number_pg2`,`1a_pregnant_pg2`,`1b_breastfeeding_pg2`,`1c_weightloss_pg2`,`1d_rinfections_pg2`,`1e_immunodeficiency__pg2`,`1f_corticosteroid_pg2`,`1g_hypertension_pg2`,`1h_severeasthma_pg2`,`1i_chroniccough_pg2`,`1j_diabetes_pg2`,`1k_rabdominalpain_pg2`,`1l_chronicdiabetes_pg2`,`1m_backjointpain_pg2`,`1n_neurohllk_pg2`,`1o_rheadaches_pg2`,`1p_bcpsych_pg2`,`1q_anemia_pg2`,`1r_phookworm_pg2`,`1s_recentvac_pg2`,`1t_transfusion_pg2`,`1u_alcoholdrugs_pg2`,`2_medical_history_pg2`,`2a_condition_pg2`,`2a_onset_pg2`,`2a_stop_pg2`,`2a_ongoing_pg2`,`2b_onset_pg2`,`2b_stop_pg2`,`2b_ongoing_pg2`,`2c_onset_pg2`,`2c_stop_pg2`,`2c_ongoing_pg2`,`2d_onset_pg2`,`2d_stop_pg2`,`2d_ongoing_pg2`,`2e_onset_pg2`,`2e_stop_pg2`,`2_ongoing_pg2`,`3_surgical_history_pg2`,`3a_description_pg2`,`3a_date_pg2`,`3b_description_pg2`,`3b_date_pg2`,`3c_description_pg2`,`3c_date_pg2`,`3d_description_pg2`,`3d_date_pg2`,`4_known_allergies_pg2`,`4a_anaphylacti__pg2`,`4b_other_pg2`,`4b_description_pg2`,`4c_other_pg2`,`4c_description__pg2`,`4d_other__pg2`,`4d_description_pg2`,`5_recent_vacination__pg2`,`5a_vaccine_pg2`,`5a_date_pg2`,`5b_vaccine_pg2`,`5b_date_pg2`,`5c_vaccine_pg2`,`5c_date_pg2`,`5d_vaccine_pg2`,`5d_date_pg2`,`5e_vaccine_pg2`,`5e_date_pg2`,`6_currentmedications_pg2`,`6a_medname_pg2`,`6a_reason_pg2`,`6a_dailydose_pg2`,`6a_route_pg2`,`6a_onsetdate_pg2`,`6a_stopdate_pg2`,`6a_ongoing_pg2`,`6b_medname_pg2`,`6b_reason_pg2`,`6b_dailydose_pg2`,`6b_route_pg2`,`6b_onsetdate_pg2`,`6b_stopdate_pg2`,`6b_ongoing_pg2`,`6c_medname_pg2`,`6c_reason_pg2`,`6c_dailydose_pg2`,`6c_route_pg2`,`6c_onsetdate_pg2`,`6c_stopdate_pg2`,`6c_ongoing_pg2`,`7_reproductivestatus_pg2`,`8_sugicallysterile_pg2`,`9_birthcontrol_pg2`,`10_Smenstration_pg2`,`initials_pg2`,`datecomp_pg2`) VALUES ('06998',null,'no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,'no','no',null,'no',null,'no',null,'no',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,'must be text',null,null,null,null,null,null,'must be text',null,null,null,null,null,null,'must be text',null,null,null,'fsterile','tubal ligation','implcontra','na',null,null);
INSERT INTO `hookworm`.`screening` (`id`,`number_pg2`,`1a_pregnant_pg2`,`1b_breastfeeding_pg2`,`1c_weightloss_pg2`,`1d_rinfections_pg2`,`1e_immunodeficiency__pg2`,`1f_corticosteroid_pg2`,`1g_hypertension_pg2`,`1h_severeasthma_pg2`,`1i_chroniccough_pg2`,`1j_diabetes_pg2`,`1k_rabdominalpain_pg2`,`1l_chronicdiabetes_pg2`,`1m_backjointpain_pg2`,`1n_neurohllk_pg2`,`1o_rheadaches_pg2`,`1p_bcpsych_pg2`,`1q_anemia_pg2`,`1r_phookworm_pg2`,`1s_recentvac_pg2`,`1t_transfusion_pg2`,`1u_alcoholdrugs_pg2`,`2_medical_history_pg2`,`2a_condition_pg2`,`2a_onset_pg2`,`2a_stop_pg2`,`2a_ongoing_pg2`,`2b_onset_pg2`,`2b_stop_pg2`,`2b_ongoing_pg2`,`2c_onset_pg2`,`2c_stop_pg2`,`2c_ongoing_pg2`,`2d_onset_pg2`,`2d_stop_pg2`,`2d_ongoing_pg2`,`2e_onset_pg2`,`2e_stop_pg2`,`2_ongoing_pg2`,`3_surgical_history_pg2`,`3a_description_pg2`,`3a_date_pg2`,`3b_description_pg2`,`3b_date_pg2`,`3c_description_pg2`,`3c_date_pg2`,`3d_description_pg2`,`3d_date_pg2`,`4_known_allergies_pg2`,`4a_anaphylacti__pg2`,`4b_other_pg2`,`4b_description_pg2`,`4c_other_pg2`,`4c_description__pg2`,`4d_other__pg2`,`4d_description_pg2`,`5_recent_vacination__pg2`,`5a_vaccine_pg2`,`5a_date_pg2`,`5b_vaccine_pg2`,`5b_date_pg2`,`5c_vaccine_pg2`,`5c_date_pg2`,`5d_vaccine_pg2`,`5d_date_pg2`,`5e_vaccine_pg2`,`5e_date_pg2`,`6_currentmedications_pg2`,`6a_medname_pg2`,`6a_reason_pg2`,`6a_dailydose_pg2`,`6a_route_pg2`,`6a_onsetdate_pg2`,`6a_stopdate_pg2`,`6a_ongoing_pg2`,`6b_medname_pg2`,`6b_reason_pg2`,`6b_dailydose_pg2`,`6b_route_pg2`,`6b_onsetdate_pg2`,`6b_stopdate_pg2`,`6b_ongoing_pg2`,`6c_medname_pg2`,`6c_reason_pg2`,`6c_dailydose_pg2`,`6c_route_pg2`,`6c_onsetdate_pg2`,`6c_stopdate_pg2`,`6c_ongoing_pg2`,`7_reproductivestatus_pg2`,`8_sugicallysterile_pg2`,`9_birthcontrol_pg2`,`10_Smenstration_pg2`,`initials_pg2`,`datecomp_pg2`) VALUES ('06997',null,'yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,'yes ','yes ',null,'yes ',null,'yes ',null,'na',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,'femaleabst','Other','transdcontra',null,null,null);
INSERT INTO `hookworm`.`screening` (`id`,`number_pg2`,`1a_pregnant_pg2`,`1b_breastfeeding_pg2`,`1c_weightloss_pg2`,`1d_rinfections_pg2`,`1e_immunodeficiency__pg2`,`1f_corticosteroid_pg2`,`1g_hypertension_pg2`,`1h_severeasthma_pg2`,`1i_chroniccough_pg2`,`1j_diabetes_pg2`,`1k_rabdominalpain_pg2`,`1l_chronicdiabetes_pg2`,`1m_backjointpain_pg2`,`1n_neurohllk_pg2`,`1o_rheadaches_pg2`,`1p_bcpsych_pg2`,`1q_anemia_pg2`,`1r_phookworm_pg2`,`1s_recentvac_pg2`,`1t_transfusion_pg2`,`1u_alcoholdrugs_pg2`,`2_medical_history_pg2`,`2a_condition_pg2`,`2a_onset_pg2`,`2a_stop_pg2`,`2a_ongoing_pg2`,`2b_onset_pg2`,`2b_stop_pg2`,`2b_ongoing_pg2`,`2c_onset_pg2`,`2c_stop_pg2`,`2c_ongoing_pg2`,`2d_onset_pg2`,`2d_stop_pg2`,`2d_ongoing_pg2`,`2e_onset_pg2`,`2e_stop_pg2`,`2_ongoing_pg2`,`3_surgical_history_pg2`,`3a_description_pg2`,`3a_date_pg2`,`3b_description_pg2`,`3b_date_pg2`,`3c_description_pg2`,`3c_date_pg2`,`3d_description_pg2`,`3d_date_pg2`,`4_known_allergies_pg2`,`4a_anaphylacti__pg2`,`4b_other_pg2`,`4b_description_pg2`,`4c_other_pg2`,`4c_description__pg2`,`4d_other__pg2`,`4d_description_pg2`,`5_recent_vacination__pg2`,`5a_vaccine_pg2`,`5a_date_pg2`,`5b_vaccine_pg2`,`5b_date_pg2`,`5c_vaccine_pg2`,`5c_date_pg2`,`5d_vaccine_pg2`,`5d_date_pg2`,`5e_vaccine_pg2`,`5e_date_pg2`,`6_currentmedications_pg2`,`6a_medname_pg2`,`6a_reason_pg2`,`6a_dailydose_pg2`,`6a_route_pg2`,`6a_onsetdate_pg2`,`6a_stopdate_pg2`,`6a_ongoing_pg2`,`6b_medname_pg2`,`6b_reason_pg2`,`6b_dailydose_pg2`,`6b_route_pg2`,`6b_onsetdate_pg2`,`6b_stopdate_pg2`,`6b_ongoing_pg2`,`6c_medname_pg2`,`6c_reason_pg2`,`6c_dailydose_pg2`,`6c_route_pg2`,`6c_onsetdate_pg2`,`6c_stopdate_pg2`,`6c_ongoing_pg2`,`7_reproductivestatus_pg2`,`8_sugicallysterile_pg2`,`9_birthcontrol_pg2`,`10_Smenstration_pg2`,`initials_pg2`,`datecomp_pg2`) VALUES ('06996',null,'no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,'no','no',null,'no',null,'no',null,'yes ',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,'fpostmeno','hysterectomy','iud',null,null,null);
INSERT INTO `hookworm`.`screening` (`id`,`number_pg2`,`1a_pregnant_pg2`,`1b_breastfeeding_pg2`,`1c_weightloss_pg2`,`1d_rinfections_pg2`,`1e_immunodeficiency__pg2`,`1f_corticosteroid_pg2`,`1g_hypertension_pg2`,`1h_severeasthma_pg2`,`1i_chroniccough_pg2`,`1j_diabetes_pg2`,`1k_rabdominalpain_pg2`,`1l_chronicdiabetes_pg2`,`1m_backjointpain_pg2`,`1n_neurohllk_pg2`,`1o_rheadaches_pg2`,`1p_bcpsych_pg2`,`1q_anemia_pg2`,`1r_phookworm_pg2`,`1s_recentvac_pg2`,`1t_transfusion_pg2`,`1u_alcoholdrugs_pg2`,`2_medical_history_pg2`,`2a_condition_pg2`,`2a_onset_pg2`,`2a_stop_pg2`,`2a_ongoing_pg2`,`2b_onset_pg2`,`2b_stop_pg2`,`2b_ongoing_pg2`,`2c_onset_pg2`,`2c_stop_pg2`,`2c_ongoing_pg2`,`2d_onset_pg2`,`2d_stop_pg2`,`2d_ongoing_pg2`,`2e_onset_pg2`,`2e_stop_pg2`,`2_ongoing_pg2`,`3_surgical_history_pg2`,`3a_description_pg2`,`3a_date_pg2`,`3b_description_pg2`,`3b_date_pg2`,`3c_description_pg2`,`3c_date_pg2`,`3d_description_pg2`,`3d_date_pg2`,`4_known_allergies_pg2`,`4a_anaphylacti__pg2`,`4b_other_pg2`,`4b_description_pg2`,`4c_other_pg2`,`4c_description__pg2`,`4d_other__pg2`,`4d_description_pg2`,`5_recent_vacination__pg2`,`5a_vaccine_pg2`,`5a_date_pg2`,`5b_vaccine_pg2`,`5b_date_pg2`,`5c_vaccine_pg2`,`5c_date_pg2`,`5d_vaccine_pg2`,`5d_date_pg2`,`5e_vaccine_pg2`,`5e_date_pg2`,`6_currentmedications_pg2`,`6a_medname_pg2`,`6a_reason_pg2`,`6a_dailydose_pg2`,`6a_route_pg2`,`6a_onsetdate_pg2`,`6a_stopdate_pg2`,`6a_ongoing_pg2`,`6b_medname_pg2`,`6b_reason_pg2`,`6b_dailydose_pg2`,`6b_route_pg2`,`6b_onsetdate_pg2`,`6b_stopdate_pg2`,`6b_ongoing_pg2`,`6c_medname_pg2`,`6c_reason_pg2`,`6c_dailydose_pg2`,`6c_route_pg2`,`6c_onsetdate_pg2`,`6c_stopdate_pg2`,`6c_ongoing_pg2`,`7_reproductivestatus_pg2`,`8_sugicallysterile_pg2`,`9_birthcontrol_pg2`,`10_Smenstration_pg2`,`initials_pg2`,`datecomp_pg2`) VALUES ('06995',null,'yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ','yes ',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,'yes ','yes ',null,'yes ',null,'yes ',null,'no',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,'fchildbearing','tubal ligation','injoralcontr',null,null,null);
INSERT INTO `hookworm`.`screening` (`id`,`number_pg2`,`1a_pregnant_pg2`,`1b_breastfeeding_pg2`,`1c_weightloss_pg2`,`1d_rinfections_pg2`,`1e_immunodeficiency__pg2`,`1f_corticosteroid_pg2`,`1g_hypertension_pg2`,`1h_severeasthma_pg2`,`1i_chroniccough_pg2`,`1j_diabetes_pg2`,`1k_rabdominalpain_pg2`,`1l_chronicdiabetes_pg2`,`1m_backjointpain_pg2`,`1n_neurohllk_pg2`,`1o_rheadaches_pg2`,`1p_bcpsych_pg2`,`1q_anemia_pg2`,`1r_phookworm_pg2`,`1s_recentvac_pg2`,`1t_transfusion_pg2`,`1u_alcoholdrugs_pg2`,`2_medical_history_pg2`,`2a_condition_pg2`,`2a_onset_pg2`,`2a_stop_pg2`,`2a_ongoing_pg2`,`2b_onset_pg2`,`2b_stop_pg2`,`2b_ongoing_pg2`,`2c_onset_pg2`,`2c_stop_pg2`,`2c_ongoing_pg2`,`2d_onset_pg2`,`2d_stop_pg2`,`2d_ongoing_pg2`,`2e_onset_pg2`,`2e_stop_pg2`,`2_ongoing_pg2`,`3_surgical_history_pg2`,`3a_description_pg2`,`3a_date_pg2`,`3b_description_pg2`,`3b_date_pg2`,`3c_description_pg2`,`3c_date_pg2`,`3d_description_pg2`,`3d_date_pg2`,`4_known_allergies_pg2`,`4a_anaphylacti__pg2`,`4b_other_pg2`,`4b_description_pg2`,`4c_other_pg2`,`4c_description__pg2`,`4d_other__pg2`,`4d_description_pg2`,`5_recent_vacination__pg2`,`5a_vaccine_pg2`,`5a_date_pg2`,`5b_vaccine_pg2`,`5b_date_pg2`,`5c_vaccine_pg2`,`5c_date_pg2`,`5d_vaccine_pg2`,`5d_date_pg2`,`5e_vaccine_pg2`,`5e_date_pg2`,`6_currentmedications_pg2`,`6a_medname_pg2`,`6a_reason_pg2`,`6a_dailydose_pg2`,`6a_route_pg2`,`6a_onsetdate_pg2`,`6a_stopdate_pg2`,`6a_ongoing_pg2`,`6b_medname_pg2`,`6b_reason_pg2`,`6b_dailydose_pg2`,`6b_route_pg2`,`6b_onsetdate_pg2`,`6b_stopdate_pg2`,`6b_ongoing_pg2`,`6c_medname_pg2`,`6c_reason_pg2`,`6c_dailydose_pg2`,`6c_route_pg2`,`6c_onsetdate_pg2`,`6c_stopdate_pg2`,`6c_ongoing_pg2`,`7_reproductivestatus_pg2`,`8_sugicallysterile_pg2`,`9_birthcontrol_pg2`,`10_Smenstration_pg2`,`initials_pg2`,`datecomp_pg2`) VALUES ('06994',null,'no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no','no',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,'no','no',null,'no',null,'no',null,'yes ',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,'Other','other',null,null,null);
```

I've tried resolving syntax errors but have had no success. I should not require a data warehouse over IP. The tables can be created locally.

Comment: Does the schema/database “hookworm” already exist?

Comment: This is MySql code and does not work in SQLite.

Comment: No, the schema does not exist yet.

Comment: If I asked you to paint the dining room - wouldn't you expect the house to exist first? Consider the first line of code "CREATE TABLE **hookworm**.screening" :: **hookworm** is the equivalent to the house in my analogy, i.e. **hookworm must exist** before you can create a table called "screening" inside it

Comment: Your code uses backticks which is common for MySQL scripts, are you trying to rebuild for SQLite? if so you might not need "hookworm" or "hookworm." in the script(s)

Comment: Paul, thank you for your reply. It doesn't matter if I create the database in SQLLite or MySQL. I would need any method to make the above readable in a user-friendly interface, such as EXCEL. How would I use MySQL to go about doing so?